# Is the red zone location entirely random?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I was told that there had to be people in the area of the red zone in order for it to spawn, is this true? I was always under the impression it was entirely random.

Comment: Good question, that is pretty good in game information if the redzone only spawns on people. I suppose one way to test would be to go through your replays and see where the redzone spawns and if there are players in it.

Comment: I keep forgetting that replays exist lol.

Comment: haha fair enough. I love them though, its fun to go back and look through games you just played. See the cool plays for another angle, and get an idea of what the other players you ran up against were doing while your were fighting/looting

Comment: If you look at map at endgame when you have a small circle, you can see red zones completly away from it. So i don't think that people need to be in the area for a red zone to spawn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are, no matter where or how many players are at grouped up, the redzone will still spawn randomly. Source:

Comment: I'm not aware of exactly when the red zone update came out but if it came out after this video it can't really be used as proof anymore.

Comment: Between experience and this video, if it's not 100% accurate it's pretty close.

Answer (score 2):

Although the developers have said that the red zone is completely random in the past. Since the red zone was updated it seems more likely to target areas where players are present or target areas that players are likely to travel into. For example, if the circle is coming in then the zone might appear between the player and the fastest route to the new circle forcing the player to enter the red zone.